# Rails Routing Error when using RESTful Paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing, restful-url

I am having a problem with my Rails application; it is not recognizing a route that *should* exist.  I've included `resources :inquiries` at the top of the **routes.rb** file, to ensure that there are the basic CRUD operations with my **inquiries** model, which is meant to catalog user-feedback for my website.  When I try to render the view for the inquiry index, I get the following error in my browser:

```
`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"inquiries"}`
```

A simple `$ rake routes` from the console shows that this isn't true: `

```
       users GET    /users(.:format)              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
             POST   /users(.:format)              {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
    sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
 new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
     session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
   inquiries GET    /inquiries(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"inquiries"}
             POST   /inquiries(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"inquiries"}
 new_inquiry GET    /inquiries/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"inquiries"}
edit_inquiry GET    /inquiries/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"inquiries"}
     inquiry GET    /inquiries/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"inquiries"}
             PUT    /inquiries/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"inquiries"}
             DELETE /inquiries/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"inquiries"}
     about        /about(.:format)              {:action=>"about", :controller=>"pages"}
      blog        /blog(.:format)               {:action=>"blog", :controller=>"pages"}
techniques        /techniques(.:format)         {:action=>"techniques", :controller=>"pages"}
   contact        /contact(.:format)            {:action=>"new", :controller=>"inquiries"}
   reviews        /reviews(.:format)            {:action=>"reviews", :controller=>"pages"}
    signup        /signup(.:format)             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
    signin        /signin(.:format)             {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
   signout        /signout(.:format)            {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
      root        /(.:format)                   {:action=>"home", :controller=>"pages"}`
```

I should mention that it is my **/inquiries/** route that fails to load, and *not* an individual show page.  The **index.html.erb** file is as follows:

```
'<h1>All Inquiries</h1>


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Link</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Body</th>
  </tr>
  <%= @inquiries.each do |inquiry| %>
    <tr>
       <td><%= link_to inquiry.id, inquiry_path %></td>
       <td><%= inquiry.name %></td>
       <td><%= inquiry.subject %></td>
       <td><%= inquiry.body[0..140] %>...</td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>`
```

Any ideas on why the application can't find the route?  Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is created by the line `<td><%= link_to inquiry.id, inquiry_path %></td>`

By using `inquiry_path`, you should appoint an inquiry to be shown. So the path should be:

```
<td><%= link_to inquiry.id, inquiry_path(inquiry) %></td>
```

If you are using RESTful paths, you could simplify it to:

```
<td><%= link_to inquiry.id, inquiry %></td>
```